# evil mode: delete word starting with backslash leaves the last character

Tags: org-mode, evil, words

I am using evil mode.

In org-mode files, when I try to delete a word with `dw` and the word starts with a `\`, the last letter of the word is not deleted.
For example, if my cursor is on the `b` of `\begin{section}` and I type `dw` I get `\n{section}` instead of `\{section}`.

This happens *only in org-mode* (not in LaTeX or text files), but I can't figure out where in this comes from in my settings. Any idea?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. Does it still happen if you start emacs without your init file via `emacs -Q`?  If not, you'll need to recursively bisect your init file to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

`(global-superword-mode 1)`
is responsible for it.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so we can mark this question as answered.